# Rendering .haml from .html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, handler, render, missing-template

I'm trying to render my HAML partial (_my_partial.haml) from my html.erb file:

```
<%= render "shared/my_partial" %>
```

And getting:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial
>   shared/my_partial with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:

I've noticed that :handlers doesn't contain **haml**.

In Gemfile I have

```
group :assets do
  gem 'haml-rails'
  ..
end
```

One thing to note: **this only happens on production environment**, e.g. when I'm using

```
RAILS_ENV production rails s
```

How can I add it there so it might try and find the partial later?

Answer (score 2):

Move `gem 'haml-rails'` out of `group :assets`. It should do the trick.

Comment: Yep, it seems to me that's the right direction. But unfortunately it didn't help here.

Answer (score 2):

It comes out that rendering HAML from ERB can be difficult :) Luckily, `render` function has `:handlers` parameter. So the following will solve the mentioned problem:

```
<%= render "shared/my_partial", :handlers => [:haml] %>
```